# nth not supported on this type: Keyword

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and as a learning exercise I'm trying to write a function that validates the present of keys in a map.

when I try to run the code below I get an error saying

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: Keyword

```
(def record {:name "Foobar"})

(def validations [:name (complement nil?)])

(defn validate
  [candidate [key val]]
  (val (get candidate key))

(def actual (every? (partial validate record) validations))
(= true actual)
```

As I understand I'm partial applying the validate function and asserting every validations function on the map - but it doesn't seem to work - so I must be misunderstanding something?

Comment: validations needs to be either a map `{:name (complement nil?)}`, or a sequence of pairs `[ [:name (complement nil?)] ]`.  (Also, `(complement nil?)` is the same as `some?`)

Comment: The problem is that `every?` applies the function to each member of `validations`, and the way you have it, the first member of `validations` is `:name`.  The error happens when clojure tries to deconstruct the keyword `:name` into the `[key val]` formal argument of `validate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the destructuring that you are using in validate: `[key val]`. Under the hood, destructuring uses the function `nth`, and that's what's failing.

Your issue is that you are passing to `every?` a list of `[keyword validation-function]`. And `every?` is iterating over each element of that list and calling the partially applied validate function with it. That means that your validate is called first with the keyword `:name` and that throws an exception, because you can not extract a `[key val]` pair out of the keyword `:name`, causing the exception.

To fix it, you need to make your validations list a list of lists as so:

```
(def record {:name "Foobar"}) 
(def validations [[:name (complement nil?)]])

(defn validate
  [candidate [key val]]
  (val (get candidate key)))

(def actual (every? (partial validate record) validations))
(= true actual)
;; => true
```

That way, `every?` is now iterating over each pair of `[keyword validation-function]`, one at a time, and calling validate with that. Since this is a pair, it can be destructured into a `[key val]` and everything works.

And just so you know, in newer Clojure versions (1.6 and above), there is now a function called `some?` which is equivalent to `(complement nil?)`.

Answer (score 1):

`every?` takes a collection as the second argument, and so does your `validate` function. Since you're passing a vector to `every?`, `validate` is being called on the contents of the vector (that is, `:name` and `(complement nil?)`). You're also missing a closing paren in the definition of `validate`. Try the following:

```
(def record {:name "Foobar"})

(def validations [:name (complement nil?)])

(defn validate
  [candidate [key val]]
  (val (get candidate key)))

(def actual (every? (partial validate record) [validations]))
(= true actual)
```

BTW, you could use `some?` instead of `(complement nil?)`